# Is there an English dub for Triage X?

Tags: triage-x

The [*Triage X* Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triage_X) states that the show was picked up by Sentai Filmworks back in 2015 for an English release.

> In May 2015, Sentai Filmworks licensed *Triage X* for an English-language release in North America, [...].

Other than that, I can’t seem to find anything else regarding the dub.

Was it ever completed?

Answer (score 1):

**No, there's no English dub for *Triage X*** (as of April 2019).

[Anime News Network](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=16596) listed Sentai Filmworks as *one of the English licensors* for *Triage X*, but there's no English cast (compared to the German's which was dubbed by TNT Media).

> **English cast**
>
> (none)
>
> ---
>
> **English companies**
>
> **Licensed by:**
>
> - Animatsu Entertainment (UK & Ireland)
> - Madman Entertainment (Australia & New Zealand)
> - Sentai Filmworks

They release the series as [a complete BD-box](https://shop.sentaifilmworks.com/products/triage-x-complete-collection) (Japanese audio with English subtitle)

> ### TRIAGE X COMPLETE COLLECTION
>
> #### SENTAI FILMWORKS
>
> Language: Japanese with English Subtitles

---

Regarding the statement on Wikipedia, the [earliest revision](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Triage_X&diff=665434950&oldid=665376316) already stated that "*In May 2015, Sentai Filmworks licensed the series for an English-language release in North America*" citing [Sentai Filmworks' official announcement](https://www.sentaifilmworks.com/news/sentai-filmworks-licenses-triage-x). The announcement only stated that Sentai Filmworks licensed the series (which is correct) but didn't say anything about English dubbing.

I think the quoted statement from Wikipedia might be ambiguous and misleading since it might either mean "English-language release with English subtitle" (which is correct) or "English-language release with English dub" (which is wrong).